# How to understand the event handler behavior in react?

Tags: reactjs

I have recently started working with React and today I came across a topic that got me confused.

The behavior of the synthetic event handlers of react irritates me a bit.
I have read that the return values of the event are annulled after calling a callback function.

**How should I understand this, and when does this happen in my case?**

As you can see in the following Image, the counter gets not incremented.

[image: Case1 Image]

But it seems that the problem can be solved, as I have illustrated in the following example.

[image: Case2 Image]

**How exactly do I have to imagine the behavior here ?**

Many thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see the event handler looks and should work fine. However, the value of `counter` is initially `undefined` and `undefined + 1` will not result in a valid number. Try setting an initial count:

```
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0)
```

Great illustrations by the way!